# Cannot change password using passwd

Tags: password

I typed the passwd command, then input the new password.

```
~$ sudo passwd
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
```

I closed this terminal and open a new one. When I was prompted to input password again, the new password was not accepted, instead the old one was accepted.

```
$ sudo apt
[sudo] password for user: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for user: 
apt 1.2.24 (amd64)
Usage: apt [options] command
...
```

What did I do wrong? How can I view my current password?

Comment: When you type `sudo passwd` you are setting root password. When you use sudo, such as `sudo apt` you use your login password. To change your user password, use `passwd` without sudo or, better if you have an encrypted home, use the graphical tools.